# Quicksort not working well

Tags: c, algorithm, quicksort

I have tried to implement a quicksort using a pseudo-code from a book(looks like the one from wikipedia), but I can't get it to make it work.

This source code:

```
int partitionare(int a[], int n, int p, int r)
{
   int x, i, j, aux;
   x = a[r]; // pivot
   i = p - 1;
   for (j = p; j < r; j++)
   {
       if (a[j] <= x)
       {
           i++;
           aux = a[j];
           a[j] = a[i];
           a[i] = aux;
        }   
   }
   aux = a[i + 1];
   a[i + 1] = a[r];
   a[r] = aux;
   return i + 1;
}
void quicksort(int a[], int n, int p, int r)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
       int q = partitionare(a, n, p, r);
       partitionare(a, n, p, q - 1);
       partitionare(a, n, q + 1, r);
    }
}
```

where p and r are the beggining and the end of the array

And the call function:

```
quicksort(a, n, 0, n-1);
```

Don't mind that second argument, n. That is just for testing purpose only.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What results are you seeing for your test input?

Comment: Ups, sorry, I forgot to mention. 
Input:  2, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4
Output: 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) the last calls inside the function `quicksort()` are to itself recursively (not to the function `partition()`)

```
void quicksort(int a[], int n, int p, int r)
{
    if (p < r)
    {
       int q = partitionare(a, n, p, r);
       partitionare(a, n, p, q - 1);     /* recursive quicksort() here */
       partitionare(a, n, q + 1, r);     /* recursive quicksort() here */
    }
}
```

Comment: My god, it works. That's how it was in my book too, but efectively, I was blind. And this problem took me 10 hours. You sir, are a life saver. Thank you very much. :)